# Autorelease pool debugging

Tags: iphone, nsautoreleasepool

"break on objc_autoreleasenopool"
How can I do that?

I searched for it but could not find any steps.

Can anyone give a number of steps on what to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on [adding symbolic breakpoints](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_a_symbolic_breakpoint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010433-CH2-SW1).

Comment: That is the best answer I could hope for. I knew it was something I was completely missing.